# How to get Laravel to ignore filepaths when searching for a class?

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, publishing

I'm developing a package for laravel, and some code needs to be completed by the Application developer (to map their models to the models of my package).

I would like to publish some model templates from my package folders to the App folders, in order to facilitate the application developer's job.

But even once the published files are filled accordingly in the App folder (in \app\Integration\myPackageName\Mapping), Laravel tries to use the unfilled files in my Package's folder (\packages\my\package\src\Mapping\Publishables), which obviously results in an error.

Is there a way to get Laravel to ignore a folder when searching for classes ? Or am I simply not using the right method for what I want to do ?

Comment: To me it feels wrong to have invalid classes in your code. Have you considered moving the configuration to configuration files (.yml for instance) instead? In case you do still want to have the incompleted classes you could [skip autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps) that specific directory.

Comment: Don't add invalid PSR-0/4 namespaced classes to your package. Bad Practice. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude classes from the classmap(s) as follows in your `composer.json`.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": ["/Tests/", "/test/", "/tests/"]
    }
}
```

Further information can be found in composer's documentation chapter

- [Exclude files from classmaps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps)

This will prevent the error-message in Laravel.

Using this technique - as in your case - for packaging classes having invalid PSR-0/4 namespaces is **bad practice**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm all for good practice, though, so what would you suggest I do to provide the application developer with pre-filled class files?

Comment: Just provide correctly namespaced abstract classes that the developers can extend from. That'd be the usual way to provide "boilerplate" classes.

Comment: I see, I'm going to do that. Thanks a lot !